# Checking if a value in an multidimensional array is equal to a string swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble checking a value in a mutlidimensional array.

I am creating an array within an array with 3 arrays inside.

The array is called profilerdata, the variable "key" is a string so it should just be three stings in these arrays.

The array in my log as a SwiftDeferredNSArray which I think is the first problem as I have read this is a non mutable array.

```
var newKeyArray = [[key],[String](),[""]]

for thing in dataArray as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
    newKeyArray[1].append("0")
}

print(newKeyArray)
profilerData.append(newKeyArray as AnyObject)
```

I then try and read the value in the array like so:

```
var n = 1
while n <= elementArray.count {
    if profilerData[n][0] as! String == headertitle {
        print("it matches")
    } else {
        print("it does not match")
    }

    n += 1
}
```

The variable "headertitle" is a string too but when this runs I get an error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x104ce8040) to 'NSString' (0x101f97c60).

This error is occuring on this line

```
if profilerData[n][0] as! String == headertitle {
```

Any help much appreciated,

p.s. Please explain quite simply as I'm new to Swift.

Comment: Can you explain why you're casting `newKeyArray` to `AnyObject`? Also, can you quote the error message more accurately and explain what line it occurs on?

Comment: Ive added those details and i tried to cast it as a String but i get an error "Cannot convert value of type '[[String]]' to type 'String' in coercion" or just leave it append(newKeyArray) which gives me the error "Argument type '[[String]]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays are one level deeper than you seem to think they are. To see this, try this code, which simplifies what you're doing:

```
let key = "key"
let newKeyArray = [[key],[String](),[""]]
var profilerData = [Any]()
profilerData.append(newKeyArray)

let oneLevel = profilerData[0] as! Array<Array<String>>
let twoLevel = oneLevel[0] // Array<String>
let threeLevel = twoLevel[0] // String
```

Comment: thank you, i was on the right track at one point but was getting a message variable has no subscript so must have been going at it wrong, thank you

Comment: Well, that's why I said you need to think about why you're casting to AnyObject. You should not be using AnyObject or Any _at all_. (I used Any in my example only to show you what you were doing.) Use real types.

Comment: So what should i be using instead as i couldnt seem to use string as it threw an error?

Comment: I can't tell you what you "should" do. I have no notion what you're even _trying_ to do. Your code is completely opaque to me. You are making an `Array<Array<Array<String>>>`. Why anyone would do that beats me totally.